# Performance problem when replacing an innerHTML text using regular expression

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am facing a performance issue when calling a method that replaces an innerHTML text using a regular expression:

```
function getReplacedText(textToReplace) {
  return textToReplace.replace(/\<img src=[\"|\']([\S\s]+\\)*([\S\s]+).png[\"|\']\/\>/i,"*$2*");
}
```

The objective behind this replacement, is to retrieve the `innerHTML` of a `contentEditable div` in a keyup handler function, and replace each `img` tag with the name of the file. This replacement is necessary in my case to know if the replaced text exceeds or not the max length allowed to the editable div.

```
function keyupHandler(event) {
  var myEditableDiv = document.getElementById("editableDiv");
  const currentText = getReplacedText(myEditableDiv.innerHTML);
  if (currentText.length >= 750) { //750 is the max length
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

For example, the wanted output for `abc <img src="assets\test\1F619.png"> def` would be `abc *1F619* def`

When I don't use the `getReplacedText` I don't have any performance problem. Could you please advise me of a better approach or a better use of the regular expression?

This is an example of the text to replace when performance begins to degrades:

```
dsd<img src="assets\test\1F619.png"/><img src="assets\test\1F619.png"/><img src="assets\test\1F629.png"/><img src="assets\test\1F630.png"/>sdfsdfsdffsdf<img src="assets\test\1F629.png"/>sdfsdsdfsdf<img src="assets\test\1F627.png"/><img src="assets\test\1F631.png"/>sdfsdfsdf<img src="assets\test\1F631.png"/>sdfsdfsdf<img src="assets\test\1F632.png"/>sdfsdfs<img src="assets\test\1F629.png"/><img src="assets\test\1F629.png"/>sdfs<img src="assets\test\1F631.png"/>df<img src="assets\test\1F632.png"/>sdfsdfsdf
```

Comment: Can you give an example text for which the operation is taking too long, and the expected output from it? Your regex looks off as well

Comment: I would be careful in gathering text strings based on the DOM. This article might be very much helpful: http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/

Would you have a different way to get the text string you're after?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I added an example text that causes the function to take too long to execute

Comment: This: _The objective...replace each img tag with the name of the file_ - then why are you running your regex replacement on every keyup? It isn't possible to construct an image tag with a single key stroke.

Comment: @Adriano Thanks for the article I will look at it

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful, though since you don't have any `/>`s, it looks like nothing should be replaced in that example? Can you show an example of what you'd want to replace with what? Or do you actually want to replace all the folder paths with just the file, eg `assets\test\1F619.png` with `1F619`?

Comment: I recommend two approaches - 1) in `keyupHandler()` test for `">` as the last two characters in the string and bail early 2) if that doesn't solve it, cache previous portions of parsed strings and concat for output.

Comment: I am using this replacement in every keyup because I must send the text under a certain format to the server (without the img tag, just the filename), and this text must not exceed the allowed maxlength, so I have to block the user from entering new characters when the limit is reached

Comment: @CertainPerformance My bad, the browser console removed the `\\` character from the img tags in the logged text, I will update my question with the right example

Comment: What are you looking to capture and replace ? https://regex101.com/r/3caeiC/1

Comment: What is your expected output for `abc<img src="assets\test\1F619.png">def`? Do you want `abc 1F619.png def`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance The wanted output for `abc <img src="assets\test\1F619.png"> def` would be `abc *1F619* def`. I will add this to the question to make it more clear, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using regular expressions to parse HTML. Use `DOMParser` instead - find `<img>` tags, and replace them a text node containing only the last part of the src:

```js
const input = String.raw`dsd<img src="assets\test\1F619.png"><img src="assets\test\1F619.png"><img src="assets\test\1F629.png"><img src="assets\test\1F630.png">sdfsdfsdffsdf<img src="assets\test\1F629.png">sdfsdsdfsdf<img src="assets\test\1F627.png"><img src="assets\test\1F631.png">sdfsdfsdf<img src="assets\test\1F631.png">sdfsdfsdf<img src="assets\test\1F632.png">sdfsdfs<img src="assets\test\1F629.png"><img src="assets\test\1F629.png">sdfs<img src="assets\test\1F631.png">df<img src="assets\test\1F632.png">sdfsdfsdf`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, 'text/html');
doc.querySelectorAll('img[src]').forEach((img) => {
  img.replaceWith(' ' + img.src.match(/[^\/]+(?=\.png$)/)[0] + ' ');
});
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

Comment: The replacement works perfectly and the performance issue has disappeared as well. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a DOM to parse html tags !!!

The fastest way to do it, and won't choke on possibly malformed html.

Find

`/<img(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\ssrc\s*=\s*(?:(['"])(?:(?!\1)[\S\s])*?((?:(?!\1|\\)[\S\s])*?)\.png\s*\1))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+>/`

Replace `*$2*`

https://regex101.com/r/bCYXV1/1

Explained

```
                        # Begin 'img' tag
 < img
 (?= \s )
 (?=                    # Asserttion (a pseudo atomic group)
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s src \s* = \s*       # src attribute
      (?:
           ( ['"] )               # (1), Quote

           (?:
                (?! \1 )
                [\S\s] 
           )*?
           (                      # (2 start)
                (?:
                     (?! \1 | \\ )
                     [\S\s] 
                )*?
           )                      # (2 end)
           \.png                  # find the 'png' file
           \s* 
           \1          
      )
 )
                        # Have the png file, just match the rest of tag
 \s+ 
 (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]? )+

 >                      # End img tag
```

```js
var input = "dsd<img src=\"assets\\test\\1F619.png\"><img src=\"assets\\test\\1F619.png\"><img src=\"assets\\test\\1F629.png\"><img src=\"assets\\test\\1F630.png\">sdfsdfsdffsdf<img src=\"assets\\test\\1F629.png\">sdfsdsdfsdf<img src=\"assets\\test\\1F627.png\"><img src=\"assets\\test\\1F631.png\">sdfsdfsdf<img src=\"assets\\test\\1F631.png\">sdfsdfsdf<img src=\"assets\\test\\1F632.png\">sdfsdfs<img src=\"assets\\test\\1F629.png\"><img src=\"assets\\test\\1F629.png\">sdfs<img src=\"assets\\test\\1F631.png\">df<img src=\"assets\\test\\1F632.png\">sdfsdfsdf";
console.log(input.replace(/<img(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\ssrc\s*=\s*(?:(['"])(?:(?!\1)[\S\s])*?((?:(?!\1|\\)[\S\s])*?)\.png\s*\1))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+>/g 
,"\n*$2*"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution it works perfectly. I am not familiar with performance tests but when running the chrome devtools, and in terms of memory use and execution time, I didn't notice any difference between the use of the RegEx solution and the DomParser one...I just would like to understand which one is the better way to parse the HTML string...thanks :)

Comment: I don't know, I guess you could wrap a performance thing around the 2 different methods and see which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe this simple expression on `s` mode might simply do the job here:

```
 <img src=["']\s*(\S+.png)\s*["']\s*>
```

or if we are not capturing the image,

```
<img src=["']\s*\S+.png\s*["']\s*>
```

would be enough.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/X7iJgW/1/)